# How to resume failed execution in MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have one requirement saying that -

a. Lets say i have 100GB of file/data

b. I have written Map Reduce job to process this data on certain logic.

c. I fired Map Reduce  job, but it failed after reading 50GB

So my question is -

*Can i resume the Map Reduce job from the 51th GB?*

Please let me know if anybody have idea on how to do it, i don't want to reprocess the data which i processed before point of failure.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brief answer: no.

And that's why working with large batch processing systems such as Hadoop or MPI is hard. Not only restarts of large jobs are inefficient from resource consumption point of view, but are also very psychologically depressive. That's why your primary goal is to reduce running time of single job to no more than couple of hours. Maybe it would be possible some day to implement "pausing" of jobs and "hot fixing" code, but currently it is not supported to my knowledge.

Solution #1. Split your job into error-prone parallelizable job and final error-free non-parallelizable job. Consider following example: you have hundreds of gigabytes of textual access logs from web server and you want to write job that will print how popular different browsers are. If you combine parsing and aggregating (summing) to a single huge job, then it's running time will be of order of days, and also chances that it will fail are very high because textual logs are usually hard to parse due to disambiguity. Much better idea is to split this job into two separate jobs:

1. First job is solely responsible for parsing log files. It prints only browser string as its output and even doesn't need to have any reducers. This job is the place for 99% of all errors because here is where parsing of "wild" data occurs. This job is parallelizable in the sense that you may split your input into chunks and process each chunk separately, so that each chunk is processed in 10-30 minutes. If job fails for some chunk, you fix it and restart; 30 minutes is not a big loss.
2. Second job is grand job that takes outputs from instances of first jobs and performs aggregation. Because aggregation code is very simple, this job is not likely to fail.

---

```
           chunk(20G)->parse-job(20G)->browsers(0.5G)
           chunk(20G)->parse-job(20G)->browsers(0.5G)
input(1T)->chunk(20G)->parse-job(20G)->browsers(0.5G)->aggregate-job->output
              ...         ....             ...
           chunk(20G)->parse-job(20G)->browsers(0.5G)
```

---

Solution #2. Sometimes you may be satisfied with result even if parts of input data are dropped out. In this case you may set options `mapred.max.map.failures.percent` and/or `mapred.max.reduce.failures.percent` to non-zero values.

Answer (score 0):

If your entire job fails, the output gets cleared, so you loose whatever you processed. However, Hadoop retries failed tasks of a job. So as long as your failure is recoverable within preconfigured number of attempts, a job will not fail and you are not going to loose output from already completed tasks.

If your failure is not recoverable, then in most cases it is your fault, and you might need to do one or more of the following:

- Fix your code, even simple bug may cause all your tasks to consistently fail
- Use less resources (e.g. care of available memory)
- Better partition the problem (see if some tasks are fed more data than others or make sure task input is getting split into smaller chunks)
- Have a bigger cluster capacity.